# Azure arm deployment fails, How can i see more details of the error?

Tags: azure, azure-deployment, azure-managed-app

I am creating a managed application and have a complex azure template.

Couple days ago i've started to get the error during deployment process.
First i though something is wrong with the template and i reverted back all template updates i've made. But now even old templates that worked fine fail on deployment stage.

I get this info in the details, which isn't really helpful:

```
{
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ApplianceDeploymentFailed",
    "message": "The operation to create appliance failed. Please check operations of deployment 'olwa41' under resource group '/subscriptions/d288d519-07cc-4537-baf9-f7e8bd616192/resourceGroups/mrg-test_managed_medx_app-previ-20220804152639'. Error message: 'At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.'",
    "details": [
        {
            "code": "Conflict",
            "message": "{\r\n  \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\"\r\n  }\r\n}"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Instructions provided on the https://aka.ms/DeployOperations don't give me anything. When I'm opening Resource group deployments there are no deployment history records.
[image]

Comment: Hi, are you certain you're under the correct subscription 'd288d519-07cc-4537-baf9-f7e8bd616192'? What happens if you go to the RG 'mrg-test_managed_medx_app-previ-20220804152639' and click in deployments, do you still don't see anything? Are there any new Azure policies that could be preventing your deployment?

Answer (score 1):

If you get a Tracking id (or correlation Id), you can run this...

```
$log = get-azurermlog -CorrelationId '________________________' -DetailedOutput

$log.properties.content[0]['statusMessage'] |convertfrom-json |% error |% details |% details
```

This has helped me out in the past.

Answer (score 0):

One way of troubleshooting is to check deployment ResourceGroup's Activity Log and Deployment (Settings) during the deployment. Another way is to enable debug logging [Enable Debug Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/enable-debug-logging?tabs=azure-powershell)